# Сorrect indexing of time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new in pandas and trying to make aggregation. I converted Dataframe to date format and made indexing change for every day.

```
model['time_only'] = [time.time() for time in model['date']]
model['date_only'] = [date.date() for date in model['date']]

model['cumsum'] = ((model['date_only'].diff() == datetime.timedelta(days=1))*1).cumsum()

def get_out_of_market_data(data):
    df = data.copy()
    
    start_market_time = datetime.time(hour=13,minute=30)
    end_market_time = datetime.time(hour=20,minute=0)

    df['time_only'] = [time.time() for time in df['date']]
    df['date_only'] = [date.date() for date in df['date']]

    cond = (start_market_time > df['time_only']) | (df['time_only'] >= end_market_time)
    return data[cond]


model['date'] = pd.to_datetime(model['date'])
new = model.drop(columns=['time_only', 'date_only'])
get_out_of_market_data(data=new).head(20)
```

what i get

```
   0    0   65.5000 65.50   65.5000 65.500  DD  1   125 65.500000   2016-01-04 13:15:00 0
   26   26  62.7438 62.96   62.6600 62.956  DD  1639    174595  62.781548   2016-01-04 20:00:00 0
   27   27  62.5900 62.79   62.5300 62.747  DD  2113    268680  62.650260   2016-01-04 20:15:00 0
   28   28  62.7950 62.80   62.5400 62.590  DD  2652    340801  62.652640   2016-01-04 20:30:00 0
   29   29  63.1000 63.12   62.7800 62.800  DD  6284    725952  62.963512   2016-01-04 20:45:00 0
   30   30  63.2200 63.22   63.0700 63.080  DD  21  699881  63.070114   2016-01-04 21:00:00 0
   31   31  63.2200 63.22   63.2200 63.220  DD  7   1973    63.220000   2016-01-04 22:00:00 0
   32   32  63.4000 63.40   63.4000 63.400  DD  2   150 63.400000   2016-01-05 00:30:00 1
   33   33  62.3700 62.37   62.3700 62.370  DD  3   350 62.370000   2016-01-05 11:00:00 1
   34   34  62.1000 62.37   62.1000 62.370  DD  2   300 62.280000   2016-01-05 11:15:00 1
   35   35  62.0800 62.08   62.0800 62.080  DD  1   100 62.080000   2016-01-05 11:45:00 1
```

the last two columns are the time interval from 20:00 to 13:30 with the indexes of change of each day and the indices of change of the day

I tried to group by the last column the interval from 20:00 one day to 13:00 the next with indexing each interval through the groupbuy
I do not fully understand the method, but for example
`new.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='17hours'))`

how to move the indexing to this interval ?

Comment: have idea make 
```new['cumsum'] = new.apply(lambda x: "%d"%(int(x[0].hour) + 1), axis=1)``` but i think is not working with my code

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a new column to represent the **market day** it belongs to. If the time is less than 13:30:00, it is yesterday's market day, otherwise it is today's market day. Then you can group by it.The code will be:

```
def get_market_day(dt):
    if dt.time() < datetime.time(13, 30, 0):
        return dt.date() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    else:
        return dt.date()


df["market_day"] = df["dt"].map(get_market_day)

df.groupby("market_day").agg(...)
```